# Database Backup failing in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I've created a cronjob for backing up database and works well locally.
Below is the code for local machine:

```
public function handle()
    {
        $date = Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y');            
        $user = env('DB_USERNAME');
        $password = env('DB_PASSWORD');
        $database = env('DB_DATABASE');
        $command = "mysqldump --user={$user} --password={$password} {database} > {$date}.sql";
        $path = 'User Database Backup/'.Carbon::now()->format('F').' '.Carbon::now()->format('Y');
        $process = new Process($command);        
        $process->start();    

        while ($process->isRunning()) {

            $public = Storage::disk('public');
            $public->put('users/'.$path.'/'.$date.".sql", file_get_contents("{$date}.sql"));       
            unlink("{$date}.sql");      
        }       
    }
```

But when i apply the same in my Laravel app in production it creates an sql file containing:

```
Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS]
For more options, use mysqldump --help
```

Below is the code im using in production app. I'm pushing the sql file to s3 storage.

```
public function handle()
    {
        $date = Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y');            
        $user = env('DB_USERNAME');
        $password = env('DB_PASSWORD');
        $database = env('DB_DATABASE');
        $command = "mysqldump --user={$user} --password={$password} {$database} > {$date}.sql";
        $path = 'User Database Backup/'.Carbon::now()->format('F').' '.Carbon::now()->format('Y');
        $process = new Process($command);        
        $process->start();    

        while ($process->isRunning()) {

            $s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
            $s3->put('users/'.$path.'/'.$date.".sql", file_get_contents("{$date}.sql"));       
            unlink("{$date}.sql");      
        }       
    }
```

Can someone tell me why this happens? And how to solve this

Comment: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup

Comment: yup i have seen this but.. my above code must work rite?

Comment: Are you sure your env's are correct?

Comment: yeah im pretty sure.. or else my migrations wouldnt work rite.... my migration command is working

Comment: path you are giving in `put()` check that

Comment: It is mysqldump complaining, not Storage. I would check path permissions for > {$date}.sql

Comment: well the sql file is being created in the path i want so i have no issues with it. The problem is with the file.

Comment: ohk if my path had no permission my unlink wouldnt work rite.

Comment: No, your sql file is NOT being created, hence the error.

Comment: ohhhhk lemme check... thanks for suggestion

Comment: yes,you are rite i changed the s3 to public in app and now it shows error that no file name exists. So it is not created. So what all access should i give to my app?

Comment: @sskoko Thanks its your information that helped me. You can add that as answer ..i will upvote it.

Comment: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Process' not found plz help me out

Comment: @NadeemIjaz use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;   ......make sure this is added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mysqldump complaining, not Storage. I would check path permissions for > {$date}.sql